# Make Keras model output a constant of certain shape

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want a Keras model which always outputs a constant value of a desired output shape.

```
def build_model(input_shape, output_shape)
    input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(512,512,3))
    x = tf.keras.backend.constant(1, shape=output_shape)
    output = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x)(x)
    model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
    return model

model = build_model((512,512,3), (512,512,32))
```

I get the following error:

Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a TensorFlow `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: Tensor("Const_3:0", shape=(512, 512, 32), dtype=float32)

How can I fix it?

### Update

Input and output are indeed not connected. I want to test the performance of my processing pipeline with the lowest GPU load possible. I think that always outputting the same value without doing any computations won't use the GPU much. But I still make sure that my data is properly loaded (input layer).

Comment: The `input` and `output` nodes are not connected. What you are trying to achieve is also not clear.

Comment: They are indeed not connected. I want to test my pipeline with the lowest possible GPU workload but still use my data for input and also my cost function (thus output needs to have a certain shape).

Comment: Have you tried outputting the input instead?

Comment: I think if you output the input, tensorflow is clever enough not to do the data transfer to GPU and back (as the address is the same). I think the easiest way is to add a linear `Activation` on the input.

Comment: @Mitiku you are correct output and input need to be connected. I can't use an activation function as the output should have a different shape than the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was indeed that output and input need to be connected. I couldn't use an activation layer because the output should be of a different shape than the input. Thus I ended up concatenating the input 11 times and slice it again to get an output of the correct shape with 0 trainable parameters.

The final model building function looks like this:

```
def build_model(input_shape=(512,512,3)):
    input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
    lamb = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.slice(tf.concat([x]*11, axis=3), begin=(0,0,0,0), size=(-1,512,512,32)))
    output = lamb(inp)
    model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
    return model
```